# Tabs navigation using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I making page with tabs . And i ahve to make tabs inside tabs which Right now i am making it as button as I am not getting how to make it as tabs.  Can anyone suggest me how to make it pls.

Below is my piece of code;

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Start Tabs !-->
    <div class="tab-container">

    <div id="c1">
        <a href="#c1" title="Projects">Projects</a> <!-- This is your actual tab and the content is below it !-->
        <div class="tab-content">  <!-- tab-container > div > div in the CSS !-->
            <button id="create">Create</button>
            <button id="edit">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use Bootstrap to achieve this.

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16466547/2408648.

Answer (score 0):

just make it with the help of css in short give it backgroud-color or backgroud-image, gradient on button and more and more you can also place div also at the place of button. As you want that's it .... its tutorials also present easily